# How do I enlarge the icons in the Firefox bookmarks-bar?

Tags: firefox, icon-themes

I have a small 13inch screen with a resolution of 3200x1800px.
Now I can change the default font-size with the Addon [NoSquint](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/nosquint/), but the icons in Firefox are still tiny.

How do I change the icon size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A nice trick here is to play with GTK dpi:

- Double dpi factor:

  ```
  gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface text-scaling-factor 2.0
  ```
- Launch Firefox
- Change back dpi factor, so it will not affect other applications:

  ```
  gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface text-scaling-factor 1.0
  ```

You may create a script for that or a desktop launcher. (You may use any float number like 1.5, 3.5...)

Reference: [ArchLinux: Applications & Desktop Environments: Gnome3 and DPI](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=120939)

Comment: You can also set the scale-factor in https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/unity-tweak-tool/

Comment: But ince this is only a trick, I leave this question open for a better answer, that really solves it for everyone without such a hack.

Comment: Since some Firefox versions it seems to be fixed and Firefox listens to the global settings of the [System wide Menu and titlebar scaling](http://askubuntu.com/questions/472262/adapt-ubuntu-to-a-high-dpi-resolution-screen/472266#472266)